# How to validate respective values based on unique keys, to do a Json response verification test using Java

Tags: java, json

I have a Json response. Here I need to do a validation test using java based on the unique key in the response. Here I want to validate based on id in the response. I am pasting a portion of the response here for your reference. Since I am a tester and new to Json it will be much appreciable if someone can help me.

I am using the below java code to avoid the Json '{' error

```
int a = entireResponse.indexOf("{");
entireResponse = entireResponse.substring(a);
```

Json response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 6160393,
    "name": "chef-haproxy",
    "full_name": "sample/chef-haproxy",
    "owner": {
      "login": "sample",
      "id": 155331,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/155331?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/sample",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/received_events",
      "type": "Organization",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/sample/chef-haproxy",
    "description": "An attempt at a tested HaProxy Cookbook for Chef with lots of bells and whistles.",
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-haproxy/deployments",
    "created_at": "2012-10-10T16:26:35Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-01-12T14:51:13Z",
    "pushed_at": "2012-11-17T20:17:42Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/sample/chef-haproxy.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:sample/chef-haproxy.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/sample/chef-haproxy.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/sample/chef-haproxy",
    "homepage": "",
    "size": 110,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "Ruby",
    "has_issues": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
  },
  {
    "id": 5829904,
    "name": "chef-protobuf",
    "full_name": "sample/chef-protobuf",
    "owner": {
      "login": "sample",
      "id": 155331,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/155331?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/sample",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/received_events",
      "type": "Organization",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/sample/chef-protobuf",
    "description": "Protocol Buffers alfresco",
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/chef-protobuf/deployments",
    "created_at": "2012-09-16T14:21:57Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-12T15:02:14Z",
    "pushed_at": "2014-10-12T15:02:13Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/sample/chef-protobuf.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:sample/chef-protobuf.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/sample/chef-protobuf.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/sample/chef-protobuf",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 98,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "Ruby",
    "has_issues": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
  },
  {
    "id": 11471217,
    "name": "django-filer",
    "full_name": "sample/django-filer",
    "owner": {
      "login": "sample",
      "id": 155331,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/155331?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/sample",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/sample/received_events",
      "type": "Organization",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/sample/django-filer",
    "description": "File and Image Management Application for django",
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sample/django-filer/deployments",
    "created_at": "2013-07-17T08:34:43Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-12-02T10:53:10Z",
    "pushed_at": "2013-07-17T09:07:47Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/sample/django-filer.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:sample/django-filer.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/sample/django-filer.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/sample/django-filer",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer/wiki",
    "size": 3431,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "Python",
    "has_issues": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "develop"
  },
  {
    "id": 21089256,
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy and more reliable if you use a JSON library to do the validation.

This [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm) will help you set up the library.

Once the set up is done, take a look at the Json data you have in [JSONViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

The data has below structure.

1. It is an array of responses.
2. Each response has id,name,fullname,owner and a bunch of other  key value pairs.
3. owner points further more attributes like login,id and so on.

Below code shows how to extract each key value pair.

```
JSONParser js = new JSONParser();
Object obj = js.parse(entireResponse);
JSONArray data = (JSONArray) obj;

for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
    JSONObject response = (JSONObject)data.get(i);
    Long id = (Long) response.get("id");
    String name = (String) response.get("name");
    String full_name = (String) response.get("full_name");
    JSONObject owner = (JSONObject) response.get("owner");
    String owner_login = (String) owner.get("login");
    System.out.println("ID :"+id);
    System.out.println("Name :"+name);
    System.out.println("Full Name :"+full_name);
    System.out.println("Owner Login :"+owner_login);
}
```

Output :

ID :6160393

Name :chef-haproxy

Full Name :sample/chef-haproxy

Owner Login :sample

ID :5829904

Name :chef-protobuf

Full Name :sample/chef-protobuf

Owner Login :sample

ID :11471217

Name :django-filer

Full Name :sample/django-filer

Owner Login :sample

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

The test library [Majx](https://github.com/qaware/majx) allows you to verify the structure and/or values of a JSON document by matching it against a pattern that is also provided as JSON.

Suppose you with to verify only a number of structural aspects or values like:

- The root of your JSON (`$`) is an array
- The array contains an object at the first position (`$[0]`) that has at least the properties `"id"`, `"name"`, `"full_name"` and `"owner"` and may contain zero or more other properties.
- You expect the `"id"` property to be equal to `6160393` and the `"name"` property to be equal to `"chef-haproxy"` but you do not care about the value of the `"full_name"` property.
- The property `"$[0].owner"` is an object that has at least the `"id"` property and may have other properties.
- The array at position `$` may contain additional objects.

Then you could use the following JSON as pattern:

```
[
  {
    "id": 6160393,
    "name": "chef-haproxy",
    "full_name": "...",
    "owner": {
      "id": 155331,
      "...": "..."
    },
    "...": "..."
  },
  "..."
]
```

Usage in a JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    String actual = <<read your JSON file as string>>;
    String pattern = <<read the JSON pattern file as string>>;

    Majx.assertJsonMatches(pattern, actual);
}
```

An error message will tell you where your JSON does not match your expectations.